# How to put posts in pages using query posts

Tags: query-posts

What is the code in order to put some posts in different pages?
I already have one but the tittle of post is missing. And  i don't know how to.

This is the code that i have now:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="innerTop">
        <div class="innerTitle clearfix"><h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1></div>
        <?php $pagedesc = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'page_description', $single = true);?>
        <?php if($pagedesc !=''){?>
        <div class="innerDesc"><?php echo $pagedesc ?></div>
        <?php }?>
</div>

<!-- begin colLeft -->
    <div id="colLeft">
<?php
$catID = 0;
if (is_page('apple')) {
  $catID=12;
} elseif (is_page('htc')) {
  $catID=13;
} elseif (is_page('nokia')) {
  $catID=14;
}

if ($catID) {
   $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
   query_posts("cat=$catID&amp;paged=$paged");
} ?>
<?php
$title = $queried_post->post_title;
echo $title;
?>



        <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

        <?php the_content(__('(more...)')); ?>

        <?php endwhile; else: ?>
        <p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
    <!-- end colleft -->

    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>  

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I would love for an answer please.

Answer (score 1):

get_posts may be easier for you to use:

```
        $args = array( 'numberposts' => 5, 'category' => '3' );
        $myposts = get_posts( $args );
        foreach( $myposts as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post); ?>
            <div <?php post_class(); ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" style="padding-bottom:5px;">
                <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <div class="post_meta"><?php twentyten_posted_on(); ?></div>
                    <div class="entryContent">
                        <?php the_content(); ?>             

                    </div>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: I'm really new at this.
There is anything i have to change on your code? 
Sorry

Comment: To not restrict by category, remove the ",'category' => '3''